# Why is a borrowed range not an iterator, but the range is?

Tags: rust, reference, iterator

An example of how a range gets consumed is:

```rust
let coll = 1..10;
for i in coll {
    println!("i is {}", &i);
}
println!("coll length is {}", coll.len());
```

This will fail with

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `coll`
   --> src/main.rs:6:35
    |
2   |     let coll = 1..10;
    |         ---- move occurs because `coll` has type `std::ops::Range<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3   |     for i in coll {
    |              ----
    |              |
    |              `coll` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
    |              help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&coll`
...
6   |     println!("coll length is {}", coll.len());
    |                                   ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
note: this function consumes the receiver `self` by taking ownership of it, which moves `coll`
```

The usual way to fix this is to borrow the `coll`, but that doesn't work here:

```
error[E0277]: `&std::ops::Range<{integer}>` is not an iterator
 --> src/main.rs:3:14
  |
3 |     for i in &coll {
  |              -^^^^
  |              |
  |              `&std::ops::Range<{integer}>` is not an iterator
  |              help: consider removing the leading `&`-reference
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&std::ops::Range<{integer}>`
  = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

Why is that? Why is a borrowed range not an iterator, but the range is? Is it interpreting it differently?

Comment: You are consuming the range, hence it cannot be used as a reference. It is not the same case a vector for example where you actually get the references inside.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To understand what is happening here it is helpful to understand how for loops work in Rust.

Basically a for loop is a short hand for using an iterator, so:

```rust
for item in some_value {
    // ...
}
```

is basically a short-hand for

```rust
let mut iterator = some_value.into_iter();
while let Some(item) = iterator.next() {
    // ... body of for loop here
}
```

So we can see that whatever we loop over with the for loop, Rust calls the `into_iter` method from the `IntoIterator` trait on. The IntoIterator trait looks (approximately) like this:

```
trait IntoIterator {
    // ...
    type IntoIter;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
}
```

So `into_iter` takes `self` by value and returns `Self::IntoIter` which is the type of the iterator. As Rust moves any arguments which are taken by value, the thing `.into_iter()` was called on is no longer available after the call (or after the for loop). That's why you can't use `coll` in your first code snippet.

So far so good, but why can we still use a collection if we loop over a reference of it as in the following?

```rust
for i in &collection {
    // ...
}
// can still use collection here ...
```

The reason is that for a lot of collections `C`, the `IntoIterator` trait is implemented not just for the collection, but also for a shared reference to the collection `&C` and this implementation produces shared items. (Sometimes it is also implemented for mutable references `&mut C` which produces mutable references to items).

Now coming back to the example with the `Range` we can check how it implements `IntoIterator`.

Looking at [the reference docs for Range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html), `Range` strangely does not seem to implement `IntoIterator` directly... but if we check the [Blanket Implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#blanket-implementations) section on doc.rust-lang.org, we can see that every iterator implements the `IntoIterator` trait (trivially, by just returning itself):

```
impl<I> IntoIterator for I
where
    I: Iterator
```

How does this help? Well, checking [further up](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#impl-Iterator) (under trait implementations) we see that `Range` does implement `Iterator`:

```rust
impl<A> Iterator for Range<A>
where
    A: Step,
```

And thus `Range` does implement `IntoIterator` via the indirection of `Iterator`. However, there is no implementation of either `Iterator` for `&Range<A>` (this would be impossible) or of `IntoIterator` for `&Range<A>`. Therefore, we can use a for loop by passing `Range` by value, but not by reference.

Why can `&Range` not implement `Iterator`? An iterator needs to keep track of "where it is", which requires some kind of mutation, but we cannot mutate a `&Range` because we only have a shared reference. So this cannot work. (Note that `&mut Range` can and does implement `Iterator` - more on this later).

It would technically be possible to implement `IntoIterator` for `&Range` as that could produce a new iterator. But the likelihood that this would clash with the blanket iterator implementation of `Range` would be very high and things would be even more confusing. Besides, a `Range` is at most two integers and copying this is very cheap, so there is really no big value in implementing `IntoIterator` for `&Range`.

If you still want to use collection, you can clone it

```rust
for i in coll.clone() { /* ... */ }
// `coll` still available as the for loop used the clone
```

This brings up another question: If we can clone the range and it is (as claimed above) cheap to copy it, why doesn't Range implement the `Copy` trait? Then the `.into_iter()` call would copy the range `coll` (instead of moving it) and it could still be used after the loop. [According to this PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21846#issuecomment-110526401) the Copy trait implementation actually existed but was removed because the following was considered a footgun (hat tip to [Michael Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221955/michael-anderson) for pointing this out):

```rust
let mut iter = 1..10;
for i in iter {
    if i > 2 { break; }
}
// This doesn't work now, but if `Range` implemented copy,
// it would produce `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` instead of 
// `[4,5,6,7,8,9]` as might have been expected
let v: Vec<_> = iter.collect();
```

Also note that `&mut Range` does implement iterator, so you can do

```rust
let mut iter = 1..10;
for i in &mut iter {
    if i > 2 { break; }
}
// `[4,5,6,7,8,9]` as expected
let v: Vec<_> = iter.collect();
```

Finally, for completeness, it might be instructive to see which methods are actually called when we loop over a Range:

```rust
for item in 1..10 { /* ... */ }
```

is translated to

```rust
let mut iter = 1..10.into_iter();
//                   ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ--- which into_iter() is this?
while let Some(item) = iter.next() { /* ... */ }
```

we can make this explicit using qualified method syntax:

```rust
let mut iter = std::iter::Iterator::into_iter(1..10);
// it's `Iterator`s  method!  ------^^^^^^^^^
while let Some(item) = iter.next() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Dang this is a good complete answer. I was thinking of the trait as implemented on it, and as distinct from the shared reference. This last line clearly explains why, e.g. some collections can do it, and the `Range` could not.

Comment: I am curious why `Range` did not do that as well? Would it not have been useful to be able to do `for i in &coll {...}`?

Comment: I'm getting to this, give me 5 more minutes ;)

Comment: I added why `&Range` can't implement `Iterator` directly and why its not really worth implementing `IntoIterator` for `&Range`- let me know if this clearly answers your question.

Comment: I guess the only missing part here is that `Range` doesn't implement `Copy`. If it did then one would remain usable after its `into_iter` call. The reasons for not implementing Copy are given here https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27186

Comment: I wish I could double-upvote this. It is quite the in-depth and complete answer. Parts of it I don't fully understand, but that is because I need to dig into how traits actually are implemented. I am going to dig more. Thank you indeed @Paul.

Comment: @deitch thank you! If you want a recommendation, pick up the "Programming Rust" book from O'reilly. I read it throughly this summer, everything I wrote here I learned from that book.

Comment: Great point @MichaelAnderson! I hadn't really considered this, but this is interesting indeed. I'll add a small part to this.

Answer (score 14):

Ranges are iterators that modify themselves to generate elements.  Therefore, to loop over a range, it is necessary to *modify* it (or a copy of it, as shown below).

Vectors, on the other hand, are not iterators themselves.  `.into_iter()` is called to create an iterator when a vector is looped over; the vector itself doesn't need to be consumed.

The solution here is to use `clone` to create a new iterator that can be looped over:

```
for i in coll.clone() { 
    println!("i is {}", i);
}
```

(Incidentally, the `println!` family of macros take references automatically.)

Comment: Much cleaner than what I did, where I converted it to a `Vec` using `.collect()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a vector:

```rust
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

The method `iter` on `Vec` returns *something* that implements the `Iterator` trait. With a vector, there is also an implementation of the trait `Borrow` (and `BorrowMut`), that does not return a `&Vec` though. Instead, you get a slice `&[T]`. This slice can then be used to iterate over the elements of the vector.

However, the range (e.g. `1..10`) implements `IntoIterator` already and does not need to be transformed into a slice or some other view into it. Therefore, you can consume the range itself by calling `into_iter()` (which you do implicitly). Now, it is as if you moved the range into some function and you cannot use your variable `coll` anymore. The borrowing syntax won't help, since this is only some special functionality of `Vec`.

In this case, you could construct a `Vec` from your range (with the `collect` method), clone the range when iterating over it or get the length before iterating (since getting the length doesn't consume the range itself).

Some references:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html

Comment: That is _precisely_ what I did, although I found it surprising I could not just get a straight reference.

Comment: Well, you can get a reference to a `std::ops::Range`, however it is not useful, since you need mutable access to iterate over it (aka consume it). This is in contrast to the `Vec`, where "getting a reference" has some more magic around it, so that you get some type other than `&Vec`, that then allows iterating over the elements, that the original vector owns.