# Why do I get the error "the trait `Iterator` is not implemented" for a reference to a generic type even though it implements IntoIterator?

Tags: rust, traits

In the following example, `MyTrait` extends `IntoIterator` but the compiler doesn't recognize it when used in a loop.

```rust
pub trait MyTrait: IntoIterator<Item = i32> {
    fn foo(&self);
}

pub fn run<M: MyTrait>(my: &M) {
    for a in my {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0277]: `&M` is not an iterator
 --> src/lib.rs:6:14
  |
6 |     for a in my {
  |              ^^ `&M` is not an iterator
  |
  = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `&M`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `&M`
  = note: required by `into_iter`
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully: `O` is iterable, but `&O` isn't.

Comment: I thought this is the issue, but it's not, I replaced &V with &Vec and it works

Comment: That's because `&Vec` implements `IntoIterator`...

Comment: And it's not just a quirk of syntax: `IntoIterator::into_iter()` takes `self`, i.e. needs to consume the value it is called on. If you have just a reference to an object, the fact that it implements `IntoIterator` is useless because you cannot use a reference to consume the object. `&Vec` provides a separate implementation of `IntoIterator` that trivially calls `self.iter()` and returns an iterator that produces references to vector elements.

Comment: So I'm not sure how do I workaround it, do I need to implement `IntoIterator` for `&OtherTrait`?

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks these are great references but I still don't get how implement `IntoIterator` for `&OtherTrait`

Comment: `impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a OtherTrait`

Comment: Look at the section [after the text "you'd need to also implement an iterator that doesn't consume it"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30220832/155423)

Comment: It feels like going down the rabbit hole, new errors are popping...

Comment: @TavianBarnes did you manage to compile it?

Comment: @Shepmaster you were right associated was a red herring, I simplified the example.

Answer (score 3):

Only `M` implements `IntoIterator`, but you're trying to iterate over a `&M`, which doesn't have to.

It's not clear what you hope to achieve with `run`, but removing the reference might be a start:

```
pub fn run<M: MyTrait>(my: M) {
    for a in my {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}
```

Note that `M` *itself* may be (or contain) a reference, so writing it in this way doesn't mean you can't use it with borrowed data. Here's one way to use `run` to iterate over a `&Vec` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e39a0d540d959af13a15b025515d55ad)):

```
impl<I> MyTrait for I
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = i32>,
{
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![10, 12, 20];
    run(v.iter().copied());
}
```

This uses `.copied()` to turn an `Iterator<Item = &i32>` to an `Iterator<Item = i32>`.

### Related questions

- [Why is a borrowed range not an iterator, but the range is?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63685464/155423)
- [Am I incorrectly implementing IntoIterator for a reference or is this a Rust bug that should be reported?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40668074/155423)
- [How to implement Iterator and IntoIterator for a simple struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30218886/155423)
- [What is an idiomatic way to collect an iterator of &T into a collection of Ts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57593717/3650362)
- [How to properly pass Iterators to a function in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57543399/3650362)

Comment: but @trentcl that is the all issue, even if I wrap `&OtherTrait` I still need somehow to iterate over  `&OtherTrait`

Comment: @GuyKorland The question doesn't contain enough context to understand how you're trying to use this. Removing `&'a` from `MyEnum` [is all you need to make your example compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8dff5851e0c2a2c2c520a7beb3119334). I can't know what other changes you might need to make the rest of your code compile, because I don't know what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: all I'm trying to do is pass a borrowed trait and iterate over it. Simplified the example

Comment: @GuyKorland The solution to the simplified example is the same: [just remove the `&`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9328526405cb376fde182978a5a000d6). You **cannot** use `IntoIterator` by reference. But you *can* still use references (and structs that contain references) which themselves implement `IntoIterator`: [for example, `Copied<Iter<'_, i32>>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e39a0d540d959af13a15b025515d55ad).

Comment: I should perhaps add that in principle you *could* fix this with a higher-ranked trait bound; however, since [where clauses are only elaborated for supertraits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20671), it [doesn't work today](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=68a4353def36553e206eba7ec91bdd47), and even if it did it still wouldn't work with `M = Vec<i32>` because `&Vec<i32>` doesn't implement `IntoIterator<Item = i32>` (it implements `IntoIterator<Item = &i32>` -- note the `&`).

Comment: `impl<'a, T, A: Allocator> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T, A> {` This is the definition it's not &T but to T.
The item is `type Item = &'a T;` but that is expected cause that is result of the iterator

Comment: @GuyKorland Yes, `&Vec<T>` is a reference and implements `IntoIterator`. What's your point?

Comment: That I still don't get how to implement `impl IntoIterator for &MyTrait`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230692/discussion-between-trentcl-and-guy-korland).